# nbconvert use '--allow-chromium-download'

Tags: python, pdf, anaconda, nbconvert

I tried downloading a Jupyter Notebook as pdf by clicking on `File` -> `Download as` -> `Pdf` via pyppeteer. I get the below error while doing so:

```
nbconvert failed: No suitable chromium executable found on the system. Please use '--allow-chromium-download' to allow downloading one.
```

I had installed pyppeteer using command `conda install -c conda-forge pyppeteer` . Now I am trying to download the pdf via Jupyter GUI but it fails.

How can I do that ? And do I need to run some Command on anaconda terminal to do it?

Answer (score 51):

Try in your terminal this command using your notebook:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to webpdf --allow-chromium-download Untitled.ipynb
```

where "Untitled.ipynb" is the name of your notebook.

this should download chromium

Comment: + You should run from inside notebook's directory
+ "Untitled" is the name of your notebook
+ After manually downloading chromium once, you can download as pdf from Jupyter

Answer (score 28):

Above issue can be fixed by installing the missing package

1. open the **anaconda terminal**
   [image]
2. Type the command `pyppeteer-install` in the **terminal**. This will download and install an appropriate version of **chromium**.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

try this:

```
pip install jinja2==3.0.3
```

this should install jinja and fix the problem