# nbconvert failed: Pyppeteer is not installed to support Web PDF conversion. Please install `nbconvert[webpdf]` to enable

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nbconvert, pyppeteer

Getting error as "nbconvert failed: Pyppeteer is not installed to support Web PDF conversion. Please install `nbconvert[webpdf]` to enable." while trying to download jupyter notebook file (.ipynb) as a PDF file

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Execute and install below packages using command prompt:

pip install nbconvert

pip install pyppeteer

Answer (score 4):

Execute the following commands in the command prompt to install nbconvert and puppeteer.

`pip install nbconvert`
`pip install pyppeteer`

If you get the error

> nbconvert failed: No suitable chromium executable found on the system. Please use '--allow-chromium-download' to allow downloading one.

then try [[Following link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66514334/nbconvert-use-allow-chromium-download)

Comment: I followed these steps but now I get this error: `ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration`

Answer (score 4):

It worked, below is full command :

#To Download the ipynb to PDF into local machine

1. `pip install nbconvert`
2. `pip install pyppeteer`
3. `jupyter nbconvert --to webpdf --allow-chromium-download untitled.ipynb`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using anaconda and have multiple python installed in your environment try to install it from anaconda interface.

1. Go to Anaconda navigator -> environments,
2. Change installer to Not installed
3. Search nbconvert
4. Check it and hit apply
5. Restart your jupyter notebook.

[anaconda screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYJga.png)

Comment: my anaconda have already installed, but still cannot export JPT notebook to pdf , it still show error